# Using flux, how can I retain groupby columns when joining data after grouping? Grouped columns are variable

Tags: influxdb

I need help debugging the following flux code.

```
left = from(bucket: "my_bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_measurement")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "specific_measurement")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => contains(value: r.strategy, set: [${strategy:doublequote}]))
  |> group(columns: [${groupBy:doublequote}])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: ${timeWindow}, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)

right = from(bucket: "my_bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_measurement")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "specific_measurement")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => contains(value: r.strategy, set: [${strategy:doublequote}]))
  |> group(columns: [${groupBy:doublequote}])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: ${timeWindow}, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)

join(tables:{left:left, right:right}, on:["_time", ${groupBy:doublequote}])
  |> map(fn:(r) => ({
    _time: r._time,
    ${groupBy}: r.${groupBy},
    _value: 100.0 * r._value_left / r._value_right
}))
```

groupBy in this case is a variable, which is a list of one or more columns. The following code works:

```
join(tables:{left:left, right:right}, on:["_time", ${groupBy:doublequote}])
  |> map(fn:(r) => ({
    _time: r._time,
    column_1: r.column_1,
    column_2: r.column_2,
    ......
    column_n: r.column_n,
    _value: 100.0 * r._value_left / r._value_right
}))
```

however the first code snippet fails, as flux does not like the use of the variable groupBy. How can I attain the same thing as the second code snippet but in a generalised way, where groupBy is an array of columns ["column_1", "column_2", ...., "column_n"]?

Here is the exact error when I run my code:

```
invalid: compilation failed: error @18:20-22:3: invalid expression @22:1-22:2: } error @18:21-20:73: cannot mix implicit and explicit properties error @20:5-20:56: unexpected token for property key: LBRACE ({) error @20:41-20:42: expected IDENT, got LBRACE ({) at 20:41 error @21:5-21:11: invalid expression @20:73-20:74: , error @21:13-21:18: invalid expression @21:11-21:12: :
```

Thanks.